# How do I export stl without the origin point being connected as vertex to the mesh?

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I have a problem in the stl's exported from my Blender file: the origin point is connected as vertex to the mesh. How do I export without this connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the "Object" tab, and select the "Origin to geometry". This will put the origin in the center of the object, which should make the object easier to export.

Comment: The result of this action is similar: there is a vertex now in the center of the object that is connected.

Comment: The origin will always be connected to the object, but you can move it by setting the cursor location, and selecting "Origin to 3D cursor" The origin is the main pivot point for rotating the object.

Comment: Thank you very much. With this input I've succeeded in exporting an stl with 'invisible' origin: I have put the origin on an edge of the mesh by use of the 3D cursor and I have put the pivot point on 3D curosr.